# Does "whenever" mean "only when" or "in all cases when"?

Tags: meaning

> This action is wrong **whenever** the sign is not red.

Does the above sentence mean

> This action is wrong **only when** the sign is not red.

or

> This action is wrong **in all cases when** the sign is not red.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, people would mean both. If we want to get picky about what is absolutely safe to logically assume, then it means "in all cases when the sign is not red." That is:

1. We know for certain that it is always wrong when the sign is not red.
2. It is probable that we wouldn't be saying this if it weren't at least sometimes right when the sign *is* red, but we don't know for sure.
3. We could mean it is always right when the sign is red, but we don't know for sure.
4. It's even vaguely possible that the action is just always wrong, whether or not the sign is red.